# Overwriting Templates with custom Module in Magento 2

Tags: magento, layout, module, magento2

I am trying to overwrite a template defined in `/vendor/magento/module-grouped-product/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view_type_grouped.xml` in a custom module. The file has a block named `product.info.grouped` defined like so:

```
<block class="Magento\GroupedProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Grouped" name="product.info.grouped" before="product.info.addtocart" template="product/view/type/grouped.phtml"/>
```

So I created a file `/app/code/FortyThree/GroupedConfigurableProduct/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view_type_grouped.xml` and in it

```
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
  <referenceBlock name="product.info.grouped">
    <action method="setTemplate">
      <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">FortyThree_GroupedConfigurableProduct::product/view/type/grouped.phtml</argument>
    </action>
  </referenceBlock>
</layout>
```

and created the corresponding .phtml file but it doesn't overwrite the original template file. Is there something else I need to do to get the overwrite to register? I've tried `setup:upgrade` and flushing the cached nothing seems to work. I also have the `Magento_GroupedProduct` set in the sequence section of my `module.xml` to make sure its loading after.

It really doesn't seem like my `catalog_product_view_type_grouped.xml` is being read at all since nothing I do in there seems to do matter.

Answer (score 0):

You layout file isn't good.

This should do the trick :

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.grouped">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">FortyThree_GroupedConfigurableProduct::product/view/type/grouped.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Also don't forget to add a dependency to GroupedProduct in your module.

There are a few ways to check if you are referencing properly a block. You could simply use a remove, to see if that works to confirm that you have the proper block.